# Is it good way for protecting the form model in Asp.Net Core MVC using DataProtection

Tags: security, asp.net-core, data-protection

I have tried create the Asp.Net Core MVC app where I want to protect the form model especially Id.

I have found the posibility with DataProtection with method - `Protect` and `Unprotect` string.

I've used this implementation:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        readonly IDataProtector _protector;
        private readonly IUserRepository _userRepository;

        public HomeController(IDataProtectionProvider provider, IUserRepository userRepository)
        {
            _protector = provider.CreateProtector("DataProtectionDemo.Controllers.HomeController");
            _userRepository = userRepository;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int id)
        {
            var user = await _userRepository.GetUserDetail(id);

            user.Id = _protector.Protect(user.Id);

            return View(user);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index(UserViewModel model)
        {
            try
            {
                model.Id = _protector.Unprotect(model.Id);

                await _userRepository.SaveUser(model);

                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                model.Error = e.Message;

                return View(model);
            }
        }
```

In this case I want to protect UserId in hidden field with encrypted string, but I don't know if this using of Dataprotection is correct way. I know of posibilities around Authorization Policy and it might be next step check user permission but I am wondering about this additional way as create better protection.

Is it good way how protect the form model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have opened this issue on Github in `DataProtection` topic:

https://github.com/aspnet/DataProtection/issues/278

The answer was that this solution should work fine.